# XPages client side: listen to and trigger an event (pure CSJS)

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I'll try to describe what I'd like to have.

At the moment, I have custom control Desk with:

- an Accordion Container (dojo)
- several Accordion Panes, of which
- one contains custom control Agenda

In custom control Agenda, there's nothing really special, expect for

- custom control Tiles

In custom control Tiles, I display meeting info in a nice way, as tiles. There can be multiple tiles on one row. In order to make things looking perfect, I have to spread these tiles over the full line, justified, using CSS (that part works, 99%). What doesn't work is that when the accordion is hidden when the page loads, I have no details on the size of each tile so I can't do my calculations (i.e. offsetWidth==0).

So I have to delay the calculations to when the accordion is activated and onShow is triggered. But how to pass this on downwards, all the way to the custom control Tiles?

Tiles is used in other places too, so it cannot be a fixed reference. It doesn't even know that it's inside an accordion...

Question: 
*How can I call/trigger a function that's inside the Tiles custom control from the top custom control, Desk, in a transparent way?*

NB A code example, even an illustrative one, would be very complicated to make (I think).

Could someone give me a push into the right direction? Events and triggers maybe? Pass accordion id down to the Tiles cc and then do something brilliant?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution right now, but it isn't exactly a beautiful and transparent one.

I gave the Tiles a styleClass="Tiles", and then I can find these Tiles using getElementsByClassName. It's not the proper way, but it's a way, the pragmatic one.